# What is the best way to create a shortcut hook mechanism for Office

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am looking to create shortcut handler for MS Office. 
I am creating an addin with VS2010 for Office 2010. The handler needs to listen to all keyboard events when Word/PowerPoint is active.

Although there is a lot of material for creating application level shortcut handlers, I couldn't find one that was specific to Office.

It would be great if somebody could suggest techniques with sample c# code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a [keyboard hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589.aspx).

Since you're creating an Office addin, you can simply set a normal keyboard hook, which will capture all input in your process.

You can see a C# example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
The sample you are referring to is for a Global keyboard hook, how can I ensure that my code only processes the keyboard events when the Office app is active.

Comment: Scroll further down that page.

Comment: Great answer slaks. If I get the time I will post my excel addin version that uses your code, I'm pretty sure it is almost the same